# Composition initialization error

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, composition

I keep getting an error saying:

> initializing cannot convert from 'const char *' to 'Address'

I am trying to allow my `Person` class to use `Address` as a parameter in the constructor. I'm including my `Address` header file in the `Person` header file so I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Also there's nothing in my `.cpp` file besides calling the default constructor `Person myPerson`.

`Address` header file:

```
#ifndef ADDRESSMODEL
#define ADDRESSMODEL
#define ADDRESSDEBUG

#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

class Address {

  public:

    Address(void);

    Address(char* aNumber,
            char* aStreetName,
            char* aTownName,
            char* aCounty);

    ~Address();

    void setAddress(char* aNumber,
                    char* aStreetName,
                    char* aTownName,
                    char* aCounty);

    char* getNumber(void);

    char* getStreetName(void);

    char* getTownName(void);

    char* getCounty(void);

  protected:

  private:

    char theNumber[4];

    char theStreetName[20];

    char theTownName[20];

    char theCounty[20];

};

inline Address::Address(void) {
  char theNumber[]     = "0";
  char theStreetName[] = "0";
  char theTownName[]   = "0";
  char theCounty[]     = "0";

  cout << "\n Default constructor was called" << endl;
}

inline Address::Address(char* aNumber,
                        char* aStreetName,
                        char* aTownName,
                        char* aCounty) {
  strcpy(theNumber, aNumber);
  strcpy(theStreetName, aStreetName);
  strcpy(theTownName, aTownName);
  strcpy(theCounty, aCounty);
  cout << "\n Regular constructor was called" << endl;
}

inline Address::~Address() {
  cout << "\n Deconstructor was called" << endl;
}

#endif // ifndef ADDRESSMODEL
```

My `Person` header:

```
#include "Date.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

class Person {

  public:

    Person(void);

    // Person(Address anAddress);

  protected:

  private:

    // Name theName;

    // Date theDate;

    Address theAddress;

};

inline Person::Person(void) {
  Address theAddress = ("00", "000", "00", "00");

  cout << "\n The default constructor was called" << endl;
}

// inline Person :: Person(Address anAddress) {
//   cout << "\n The regular constructor was called" << endl;
// }

#endif
```

Comment: There are many bugs in your code. Rather use `std::string` than `char` arrays.

Comment: Regarding your multitude of bugs, one of them is that the `Address` default constructor doesn't initialize the member variables. Instead it defines its own *local* variables.

Comment: As for your question, please copy-paste the complete error (in full, and including any possible informational notes) into the question *as text*. Then add e.g. a comment on the line where you get the error. And lastly [read about the comma operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_other#Comma_operator).

Comment: OK thank you to @Someprogrammerdude for pointing out my problem in the default constructor. Fixed almost all my errors.

Comment: @EoinCoogan The error you mention is caused by the confusing (confused?) `Address theAddress = ("00","000","00","00");` which is (practically) the same as `Address theAddress = "00";`. If you keep reading that source you have for learning C++ it should become clear, and you'll be able to solve the numerous other errors in your code.

Comment: Why don't you use one of your constructors for address instead of that = (...) stuff? That part is quite unreadable. Also, you really want to go through a basic tutorial and start with smaller classes. Making your code clean would mean to rewrite it. If you want me to, I'll rewrite your class in an answer. Although I'd simply make Address a structure, I see no need to encapsule an actual data holder like that.

Answer (score -1):

First of All re-check if you are including the correct header file in the person Class , I think you have included the "Date.h" which might not be the correct file, You should check it Again.
Then in the constructor of Person class you are re-declaring the theAddress Attribute which is already declared as the private attribute.
it should be something like this:

```
   #include "Date.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string.h>

   using namespace std;
   class Person
   {
   public:
 Person(void);
//Person(Address anAddress);
    protected:

    private:
//Name theName;
//Date theDate;
Address theAddress;
    };

    inline Person :: Person(void) 
   {

   theAddress = ("00","000","00","00");
    cout << "\n The default constructor was called" << endl;
    }
```

you can't call the constructor and re-declare the attribute again.
You should use constructor initializer list instead to call the required constructor of Address class.